# dropdown list data binding

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I'm new to angular (not angularJs)and there is some stuff that i don't know how to do with typescript.

I have a dropdown list (primeng) that I'm using to search users and display the results in a table (dataTable of Primeng), and what i want to do is when i  select a username for exp, i only find his related data in the next dropdown list .
How can i do this ? 
html template :

```html
<p-dataTable #dataTable [value]="tableUserList"  [(selection)]="selectedUsers" selectionMode="multiple">
    <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" >
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

table ts :

```html
export class UserTableComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input('tableUserList') TableUserList: User[];
  @ViewChild('dataTable') dataTable: DataTable;
  @ViewChild('multiselect') multi: MultiSelectComponent;

  UserDatas: Response;
  selectedTableUserList: any[];
  selectedUsers : User[];
  columns: any[];
  rowsPerPage: number;
  firstRowIndex = 1;
  totalRecords = 0;
  cols: any[];

  constructor(private UserTable: AdminService) {
    this.selectedTableUserList = [];
    this.rowsPerPage = 10;
    this.firstRowIndex = 1;
    this.tableUserList = [];

    this.cols = [
      { field: 'givenName', header: 'Nom' },
      { field: 'familyName', header: 'Prenom' },
      { field: 'mail', header: 'email' },
      { field: 'cuid', header: 'Cuid' }
    ];
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.tableUserList && this.tableUserList.length) {
      this.totalRecords = this.tableUserList[0].userCount;
      this.firstRowIndex = 0;
    }
    this.selectedTableUserList = [];
  }


}
```

user search ts :

```html
export class UserSearchComponent {
  @Output() onSearch = new EventEmitter<any>();
  UserDatas: Response;
  user: User;

  searchForm: FormGroup;
  errormessages: string;
 collapsed = true;

  SelectedUser: User;
  givenNames: SelectItem[];
  familyNames: SelectItem[];
  mails: SelectItem[];
  cuids: SelectItem[];

  selectedFamilyNamee:string;


  constructor(fb: FormBuilder,
    private http: Http,
    private _userSearchService: AdminService
  ) {
    this.searchForm = fb.group({
      'selectedGivenName': null,
      'selectedFamilyName': null,
      'selectedCuid': null,
      'selectedMail': null
    });

    this.givenNames = [];
    this.familyNames = [];
    this.cuids = [];
    this.mails = [];

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._userSearchService.findAll()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.UserDatas = data;
        console.log(this.UserDatas);
      });
  }

  onSubmit(searchFormValue): void {
    if (this.isValid(searchFormValue)) {
      if (searchFormValue === searchFormValue.SelectedUser) {

      }
      let user = {
        givenName: searchFormValue.selectedGivenName,
        familyName: searchFormValue.selectedFamilyName,
        cuid: searchFormValue.selectedCuid,
        mail: searchFormValue.selectedMail
      }
      this.onSearch.emit(user);
      this.errormessages = '';
    }
  }

  onSelected(formModel) {
    this.searchForm.patchValue({
      'selectedGivenName': formModel.givenName,
       'selectedFamilyName': formModel.familyName,
         'selectedCuid': formModel.cuid,
         'selectedMail': formModel.mail
    });
  }


  
}
```

form template :

```html
 <div class="nd_panel form_filter_home fixed" id="panel-filter-search-container">
  <h6>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter text-primary"></span>
    <label>{{ 'search-filtre' | translate }}</label>
  </h6>
   <div class="nd_panel_content collapse" [ngClass]="{'in': !collapsed}" id="filters">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="panel-filter-search">
      <form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(searchForm.value)">
        <span class="text-danger" id="message-valid-filter-search">{{errormessages}}</span>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-2" id="givenName-filter-search">
            <p-dropdown [options]="UserDatas" (onChange)="onSelected($event.value)" filter="filter" placeholder="Nom" optionLabel="givenName"
              [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [formControl]="searchForm.controls['selectedGivenName']">
            </p-dropdown>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 help-container">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign text-primary" pTooltip="Choisissez un nom" tooltipPosition="top"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2" id="familyName-filter-search">
            <p-dropdown [options]="UserDatas"  filter="filter" (onChange)="onSelected($event.value)" placeholder="Prenom" optionLabel="familyName"
              [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [formControl]="searchForm.controls['selectedFamilyName']">
            </p-dropdown>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 help-container">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign text-primary" pTooltip="Choisissez un prenom" tooltipPosition="top"></span>
          </div>
           <div class="col-xs-2" id="cuid-filter-search">
            <p-dropdown [options]="UserDatas" filter="filter" (onChange)="onSelected($event.value)" placeholder="CUID" optionLabel="cuid"
              [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [formControl]="searchForm.controls['selectedCuid']">
            </p-dropdown>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 help-container">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign text-primary" pTooltip="Choisissez un CUID" tooltipPosition="top"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2" id="mail-filter-search">
            <p-dropdown [options]="UserDatas" filter="filter" (onChange)="onSelected($event.value)" placeholder="e-mail" optionLabel="mail"
              [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [formControl]="searchForm.controls['selectedMail']">
            </p-dropdown>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 help-container">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign text-primary" pTooltip="Choisissez un e-mail" tooltipPosition="top"></span>
          </div>
        </div> <br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="submit-button-filter-search"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>Search</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form> 
        </div>
   </div>
   <br>
 </div>
```

PS : my user's data is mocked in a json file

```html
@Injectable()

export class UserService {

selectedData: any;
constructor(private http: Http) {}

  findAll(): Observable<Response> {
   return this.http.get('../../assets/mock-data/data.json').map(res => res.json().UserDatas) 
}
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Please share more code because I don't really understand. You have two dropdown lists and a table ?

Comment: @Antikhippe yes sorry i will share more code, i have 4 dropdown lists  i just gave you an exp with just two of them

Comment: @Antikhippe i just edited my post and added the rest of the code :)

Comment: Is is wanted to set `[options]="UserDatas"` for each of your `p-dropdown` ?

Comment: yes it's to display the dropdown's list ^^ is it because of it ?

Comment: I think so. In my opinion, you should have different options lists (one for the names, one for the cuids, ...)

Comment: yes you're right , i will do it ! thanks :)

Comment: i forgot to tell you  that the pb is solved :)